# Input field using tailwind 2.2.16 in django form

Tags: css, django, input, frontend, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind 2.2.16 in my Django project. I want to style the form, but the input fields are misbehaving and a weird looking border is encircling them. Please help me create a decent looking input field.

```
<form method="post" class="bg-green-200 shadow-lg m-10 rounded p-10 w-2/5">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label class="text-gray-700 text-xl font-bold" for="username">Username</label>
                <div class="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 mr-10">{{form.username}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <label class="text-gray-700 text-xl font-bold" for="username">Password</label>
                <div class="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 mr-10">{{form.password}}</div>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
```

[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg1Iz.png)